# Square root cubature Kalman filter stability

Tags: least-squares, kalman-filter

*Square root cubature Kalman filter gain $\mathbf{K}_k$ *directly without the need for a matrix inversion:*

Efficient least-squares: The least-squares method is used to compute the Kalman filter gain. If we substitute the innovation covariance matrix by its square-root representation we get the following expression:

$\mathbf{K}_k\left(\mathbf{S}_{yy,k|k-1}\mathbf{S}_{yy,k|k-1}^T \right)= \mathbf{P}_{xy,k|k-1}$

The square root cubature Kalman filter use the symbol / (as  it  is  a  common 
notation in Matlab), to represent the matrix right divide operator. When we perform the operation $\mathbf{A}/\mathbf{B}$, it applies the back substitution algorithm for an upper triangular matrix $\mathbf{B}$ and the forward sub- stitution algorithm for a lower triangular matrix $\mathbf{B}$:

$\mathbf{K}_k= \left(\mathbf{P}_{xy,k|k-1}/\mathbf{S}_{yy,k|k-1}^T \right)/\mathbf{S}_{yy,k|k-1}$

Now the it seems that the problem of matrix inversion is overcome, but I still get in this message in the Matlab command for some state estimation problems:

**Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.**

**Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate.**

Is this expression of the Kalman gain can hold even when $\mathbf{S}_{yy,k|k-1}$ or $\mathbf{S}_{yy,k|k-1}^T$ are singular or nearly singular?